# How to put characters into dataframe using dplyr::rename()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using ArrayExpress dataset to build a dataframe, so that I can run in gene pattern.

In my folder, *GSE11000*, there is a bunch of files, which file name is in this patter,

```
GSM123445_samples_table.txt
GSM129995_samples_table.txt
```

Inside each file, the table is in this pattern

```
Identifier     VALUE
     10001   0.12323
     10002   0.11535
```

I have a dataframe, *clinical_data*, that include all the file I want, which is in this pattern

```
                     Data.File      Samples     OS.event
1  GSM123445_samples_table.txt    GSM123445            0
2  GSM129995_samples_table.txt    GSM129995            0
3  GSM129999_samples_table.txt    GSM129999            1
4  GSM130095_samples_table.txt    GSM130095            1
```

I want to create a dataframe which should like this

```
     Identifier  GSM123445  GSM129995  GSM129999  GSM130095
 1       10001     0.12323    0.14523    0.22387    0.56233
 2       10002     0.11535    0.39048    0.23437   -0.12323
 3       10006     0.12323    0.35634    0.12237   -0.12889
 4       10008     0.11535    0.23454    0.21227    0.90098
```

This is my code

```
library(dplyr)
setwd(.../GSE11000)
file_list <- clinical_data[, 1] # create a list that include Data.File
for (file in file_list){
  if (!exists("dataset")){     # if dataset not exists, create one
     dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t") #read txt file from folder
     x <- unlist(strsplit(file, "_"))[1] # extract the GSMxxxxxx from the name of files
     dataset <- rename(dataset, x = VALUE) # rename the column
  }     
  else {
     temp_dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t") # read file
     x <- unlist(strsplit(file, "_"))[1]
     temp_dataset <- rename(temp_dataset, x = VALUE)    
     dataset<-left_join(dataset, temp_dataset, "Reporter.Identifier")
     rm(temp_dataset)
  }
}
```

My outcome is this

```
     Identifier        x.x        x.y        x.x        x.y
 1       10001     0.12323    0.14523    0.22387    0.56233
 2       10002     0.11535    0.39048    0.23437   -0.12323
 3       10006     0.12323    0.35634    0.12237   -0.12889
 4       10008     0.11535    0.23454    0.21227    0.90098
```

This is because the rename part had failed to work.

Anyone have any idea how can I solve this problem? and anyone can make my code more efficiency?

If you can tell me how to use bioconductor so that I can work with this data, I will be grateful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @jdobres but using `dplyr` (and `spread`):

First, to create some sample data files:

```
set.seed(42)
for (fname in sprintf("GSM%s_samples_table.txt", sample(10000, size = 4))) {
  write.table(data.frame(Identifier = 10001:10004, VALUE = runif(4)),
              file = fname, row.names = FALSE)
}
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "GSM.*")
file_list
# [1] "GSM2861_samples_table.txt" "GSM8302_samples_table.txt"
# [3] "GSM9149_samples_table.txt" "GSM9370_samples_table.txt"
read.table(file_list[1], skip = 1, col.names = c("Identifier", "VALUE"))
#   Identifier     VALUE
# 1      10001 0.9346722
# 2      10002 0.2554288
# 3      10003 0.4622928
# 4      10004 0.9400145
```

Now the processing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mapply(function(fname, varname)
           cbind.data.frame(Samples = varname,
                            read.table(fname, skip = 1, col.names = c("Identifier", "VALUE")),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
       file_list, gsub("_.*", "", file_list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  spread(Samples, VALUE)
#   Identifier   GSM2861   GSM8302   GSM9149   GSM9370
# 1      10001 0.9346722 0.9782264 0.6417455 0.6569923
# 2      10002 0.2554288 0.1174874 0.5190959 0.7050648
# 3      10003 0.4622928 0.4749971 0.7365883 0.4577418
# 4      10004 0.9400145 0.5603327 0.1346666 0.7191123
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry, may be I did not make my did not state it clearly, since inside the folder there is some .txt files that I dont want to select, so I have to use a list to select those file I want to create the data frame. Your way didnt not include this part. Can you modified your code so I can fit my problem?

Comment: Just replace `files` with your `file_list`?

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Comment: The code did not work just be replacing files with file_list. So I am trying to understand your code, especially mapply. Hope it work out eventually.

Comment: What do you mean by *"did not work"*? Did you get a `could not fund ...` error or something similar, or did it work without error but give you incorrect output?

Comment: After I run the code, the console shows an error, "Error in read.table... : 'file' must be a character string or connection ". I am not sure if this problem is due to the file format in my folder or the file_list I used.

Comment: I guess I was too subtle: ***post your error*** if you want any kind of assistance.

Comment: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121117/discussion-between-r2evans-and-pill45).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if this will work, since your example isn't quite reproducible, but here's how I'd tackle it.

First, read all of the data files into one large data frame, creating an extra column called "sample" which will hold your sample label.

```
library(plyr)

df <- ddply(clinical_data, .(Data.File), function(x) {
    data.this <- read.table(x$Data.File, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    data.this$sample <- x$Samples
    return(data.this)
})
```

Then use the `tidyr::spread` function to create a new column for each "sample" with the values in the "VALUE" column.

```
library(tidyr)
df <- spread(df, sample, VALUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But may be I did not make it clearly, since inside the folder there is some .txt files that I dont want to include into my dataframe, so I use a list to select those file I want. Can you modified your code so I can fit my problem? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the `dir()` command, specifically the `pattern` argument, which allows you to get a list of files from a folder that match a specific pattern.